# A network error occurred while sending your login information

Tags: ajax, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

First time I saw this error while login into my cpanel
However my internet connection is fine for all browsing.

My FTP also connected to the server but still unable to login.

Hosted Server Hostgater

> A network error occurred while sending your login request. Please try
>   again. If this condition persists, contact your network service
>   provider.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the cache of your browser or use an other browser.
You might also check if your internet connection IP is blocked with your provider in cPHulk.